# NSKeyedArchiver decode Objective-C plist in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, nskeyedunarchiver

I am updating an application from Objective-C to Swift and cannot get a `.plist` file that was encoded in Objective-C to be read and decoded in Swift.  I have added a bridged header file to use my old objects, but everything I have tried ends up with a `nil` object.  Opening up the file in Xcode shows all of the data.

```
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
    do {
        let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: url)

        if let data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? NSMutableArray {
            print("\(data)")
        } else {
            print("failed")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: The `NSKeyedArchiver` format and plists are not the same thing. You should take a look at [`PropertyListSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistserialization) instead. Regardless, we'll need to see what your data looks like to give a thorough explanation of what's happening and why.

Comment: I think you are confused. `NSKeyedArchiver` saves a serialized object as a `plist`.  This is a difference between Objective-C and Swift.  This does not have to do with the data.

Comment: `NSKeyedArchiver` might write out a file using the plist format, but you cannot use it to load an arbitrary plist. It wasn't 100% clear from your question that you meant that it was a file written with `NSKeyedArchiver` and not just an arbitrary plist.

Comment: If your file was written out with `NSKeyedArchiver`, you should be able to get it back both in Objective-C and Swift. If you remove the `as?`-cast, does it still print "failed", or do you see data?